# Django - forms.py validation issues

Tags: django, python-2.7, validation, django-forms

Im having trouble with my forms validation, I created my methods that verify if the email exist and so, if it does exist then the data cannot be saved in the database, but in my personal case it saves it anyway

Here is my Code:

**models.py:**

```
from django.db import models
from promSpace.models import Space

class StudentRegistration(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=20, default="", null=False)
    prom_code = models.CharField(max_length=8, default="", null=False)
    gender = (
    ("M","Male"),
    ("F","Female"),
    )
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=gender, default="M", null=False)
    prom_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, default="N/A")
```

**forms.py:**

```
from django import forms            
from django.contrib.auth.models import User   
#from models import StudentRegistration
from django.forms import ModelForm
from promSpace.models import Space
from StudentUsers.models import StudentRegistration
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm  



class MyRegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    prom_code = forms.CharField(max_length = 8)
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=50)

    def email_al_exist(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        if StudentRegistration.objects.filter(email = email).exists():
            raise ValidationError("Email already exists")
        return email


    def clean_password2(self):
        password = self.cleaned_data.get('password')
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get('password2')
        if password and password2:
            if password != password2:
                raise forms.ValidationError(("The two password fields didn't match."))
        return password2


    def prom_code_exist(self):
        prom_code_value = self.cleaned_data['prom_code']
        prom_code_ver = Space.objects.get(prom_code = prom_code_value)
        if Space.objects.filter(prom_code = prom_code_value).exists():
            return prom_code_value
        else:
            raise forms.ValidationError(("Error, Code doesn't exist."))


    class Meta:
        model = StudentRegistration
        fields = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name','gender','prom_code','password')
```

Observation: The users im creating here are being saved in their own table(StudentRegistration) , they have no relations with the auth_user (the default one)

Answer (score 1):

Your  `email_al_exist` method never get's called. Certainly not in the code that you have posted here anyway. You should perhaps rename it to clean_email.

```
def clean_email(self):
    email = self.cleaned_data['email']
    if StudentRegistration.objects.filter(email = email).exists():
        raise ValidationError("Email already exists")
    return email
```